# Why Libgdx increasing heap continuously?

Tags: memory-leaks, libgdx, heap-memory

**Why heap going up with no reasons? if you said use gc, I'll still wondering WHY going up?**

here is my code:

```
public class GameCore extends ApplicationAdapter {
    SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture texture;
    StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
    long current, held;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("badlogic.jpg"));
        sw.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(texture, 0, 0);
        batch.end();

        if (Gdx.app.getJavaHeap() > held) {
            current = Gdx.app.getJavaHeap();
            held = current;
            String f = "UP: " + Mis.formatMilliseconds(sw.getCurrent()) + "\t"
                    + Mis.ramStatistics(Mis.BYTE_TO_MB_FACTOR, true) + "\t, byGdx:" + Gdx.app.getJavaHeap();
            System.out.println(f);
        } else if (Gdx.app.getJavaHeap() < held) {
            // if gc worked
            held = current;
            String f = "DOWN: " + Mis.formatMilliseconds(sw.getCurrent()) + "\t"
                    + Mis.ramStatistics(Mis.BYTE_TO_MB_FACTOR, true) + "\t, byGdx:" + Gdx.app.getJavaHeap();
            System.out.println(f);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
    }
}
```

**unfortunate results:**

```
UP: 1 ms    Heap: (11/1796) MB, 0.59153545% , byGdx:11140048
UP: 58 sec, 58171 ms    Heap: (12/1796) MB, 0.62772965% , byGdx:11821672
UP: 1 min, 111 sec, 111705 ms   Heap: (12/1796) MB, 0.66392213% , byGdx:12503264
UP: 32 min, 1978 sec, 1978210 ms    Heap: (25/1796) MB, 1.3516115%  , byGdx:25454120
UP: 48 min, 2887 sec, 2887645 ms    Heap: (31/1796) MB, 1.6773589%  , byGdx:31588736
```

After 56 min of increasing (up to 34mb), gc cleaned up (26mb), libgdx started again increasing the heap size for no particular reasons.

what pushed me to ask this question is a very tiny game has only 2 texture, libgdx caused 66mb within 2 minutes, I thought I'm using libgdx wrongly, but I am not.

Comment: Are you constantly loading objects into memory? Ie loading an image every frame?

Comment: No I'am not, as you can see nothing there except what is there.

Answer (score 3):

Java is a managed language, which means that it (the JVM/GC) manages the memory for you. So unless you have an actual issue (e.g. you run out of memory), it is typically not very useful to add any conclusion solely based on the overall memory usage. For all you know, the JVM/GC might have never released any (temporary) objects yet, simply because there was no reason to do so.

If you think there really is an issue caused by too much memory usage (e.g. you run out of memory), then you better use a profiler to actually see what's going on. But from your description it looks like you don't have an actual issue.

Comment: Your answer will make sense if there are no conditions to restrict the multiple creation

Comment: I don't have a clue what you mean, can you rephrase your question?

Comment: the heap size increment happens before the IF statement, which make no sense to blame the creation of Strings or any other Objects, actually the total Strings has been created were 13, I don't think 13 Strings will misuse the heap size

Comment: Ow, I see what you mean. I've removed that example from the answer.